# How to run db.eval with authorization in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I've tried a function with db.eval but it doesn't work, it thrown an exception that says - *not authorized on 'myCollection' to execute command { $eval: \"FunctionX()\"}*.

The authorization is enabled

I've also maken a role like this:

```
{ createRole: "RunEval",
    privileges: [
        { resource: { anyResource: true }, actions: ["anyAction"] }
    ],
    roles: []
}
```

and added the role to user.

I use MongoDB v2.6

Anybody may help me?

Comment: Can you provide the user details (`getUser`)? It's best not to use eval if you can avoid it. What are you using eval for?

Comment: {
    "_id" : "mycollection.myuser",
    "user" : "myuser",
    "db" : "myCollection",
    "credentials" : {
        "MONGODB-CR" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
    },
    "roles" : [ 
        {
            "role" : "userAdmin",
            "db" : "MyCollection"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "myCollection"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "dbAdmin",
            "db" : "myCollection"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "runEval",
            "db" : "myCollection"
        }
    ]
}

I want to execute a function stored in the server

Comment: Well, I decided not to use eval, I've made a function to client side.

I don't know why can't run the function with eval in server side, I did all options for it.

I hope find the answer and post it here

Thank you for all.